# How to return a record that contains bundle.inputData.name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rest, integration, zapier

I'm trying this and receive all records. I only want to return the ones that match `bundle.inputData.name`

```
let options = {
  url: 'hidden',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-ACCESS-TOKEN': bundle.authData.access_token
  },
  params: {
    'name': bundle.inputData.name,
    'access_token': bundle.authData.access_token
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;

    return results;
  });
```

Here's a sample response, and I'd like to know how to pull `Project 2`:

```
{
  "id": 10001,
  "name": "Project 1",
  "mediaCount": 2,
},
{
  "id": 10002,
  "name": "Project 2",
  "mediaCount": 2,
},
{
  "id": 10003,
  "name": "Project 3",
  "mediaCount": 2,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to get only name so in this case  you can use map() function pretty cool
`let newResponse=response.map((item,index)=>{ return item.name;})`
and it will fine.

and if you want only one record so you can

```
let newResponse=response.map((item,index)=>{ if(item.name=="project2"){return item}});
```